# Rewriting directives to not use isolate scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two simple directives that I want to apply to an element.

This directive gives focus to a particular element when a condition changes to be true:

```
.directive('focusOnCondition', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            condition: '=focusOnCondition',
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            scope.$watch('condition', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        el[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This directive calls a function when the user presses 'enter':

```
.directive('triggerOnEnter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            func: '&triggerOnEnter'
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            $(el).keypress(function (event) {
                if (event.which == 13) scope.func();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

These two directives work separately, but they don't work if I try to apply them to the same element. For example:

```
<form ng-show="pastingResults">

    <textarea placeholder="Paste results and press 'enter'"
              ng-model="pastedResultData"
              trigger-on-enter="pasteResults()"
              focus-on-condition="pastingResults"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" ng-click="pasteResults()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Result in an error, `[$compile:multidir] Multiple directives (...) on (...)`.

How can I resolve this? I am new to Angular JS, and 'put it in an isolated scope' is the only thing I know how to do when making directives. I assume it must be possible to implement these without using an isolated scope, but I don't know how.

Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the isolated scopes, you can access the options by looking at the attributes on the element directly using the attrs object passed to the linking function, together with `$eval` to evaluate it if needs be:

```
app.directive('focusOnCondition', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.focusOnCondition, function (value) {
        if (value) {
          $timeout(function () {
            el[0].focus();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and

```
app.directive('triggerOnEnter', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, el, attr) {
      $(el).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
          scope.$eval(attr.triggerOnEnter);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

These can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/1iOBNVlmRxm8HGRrObBd?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for these examples, I didn't know it was possible to use `$watch` and `$eval` like that.